# Spacing between markers in scatter plot Matlab

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure

I have 6 scatter plots in one figure as shown below.

```
A=rand(10,2); 
B=rand(10,2); 
C=rand(10,2);
figure();
hold on;
scatter( 1:10, A(:,1), 'r*');
scatter( 1:10, A(:,2), 'ro'); 
scatter( 1:10, B(:,1), 'b*'); 
scatter( 1:10, B(:,2), 'bo'); 
scatter( 1:10, C(:,1), 'g*'); 
scatter( 1:10, C(:,2), 'go');
```

I wonder if I can make some spacing between the points so that no two points overlay each other. So for example, on the value `1` of x-axis there will be 6 different points (one representing each scatter plot), so I'm wondering how I can make each one has its one vertical lane?

So if I used `stem` instead of using `scatter` you'll see that the stem lines overlay and it makes it harder to view the plot as shown below in the screenshot. So for every xtick it has 6 stems, and I'm wondering if there is anyway I can shift 5 of the 6 stems a little bit so that they all appear.

So this is a screenshot of my current stems overlaying:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apply a small displacement to the *x* values?

```
x = 1:10;
y1 = rand(1,10);
y2 = rand(1,10);
y3 = rand(1,10); %// example data
delta = .004; %// displacement step, relative to x range
x_range = max(x)-min(x);
Delta = range*delta;
hold all
stem(x-Delta, y1, 'o');
stem(x,       y2, '*');
stem(x+Delta, y3, 's');
```

Example:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

My **first answer** would be that it is not possible. If you have 2 dimensional data and some data overlaps other data, **you cannot modify data** to improve the visualization!

If you need to improve it, you can use a third dimension:

```
figure();
hold on;
scatter3( 1:10, A(:,1), 1*ones(1,10), 'r*');
scatter3( 1:10, A(:,2), 2*ones(1,10), 'ro'); 
scatter3( 1:10, B(:,1), 3*ones(1,10), 'b*'); 
scatter3( 1:10, B(:,2), 4*ones(1,10), 'bo'); 
scatter3( 1:10, C(:,1), 5*ones(1,10), 'g*'); 
scatter3( 1:10, C(:,2), 6*ones(1,10), 'go');
```

In the Z axis, you have data separated by "lanes" as you asked. So now is up to you and your users to select the best visualization planes.

A **second straighfordward solution** to split it lines is to divide all the scatter plots in different subplots:

```
figure();
subplot(6,1,1)
scatter( 1:10, A(:,1), 'r*');
subplot(6,1,2)
scatter( 1:10, A(:,2), 'ro'); 
subplot(6,1,3)
scatter( 1:10, B(:,1), 'b*'); 
subplot(6,1,4)
scatter( 1:10, B(:,2), 'bo'); 
subplot(6,1,5)
scatter( 1:10, C(:,1), 'g*'); 
subplot(6,1,6)
scatter( 1:10, C(:,2), 'go');
```

Comment: First, Thanks for your answer. But honestly this is not what I'm looking for. Like if you used `stem` instead of using `scatter`  (I updated my question) you'll see that the stem lines overlay and it makes it harder to view the plot. So for every xtick it has 6 stems, and I'm wondering if there is anyway I can shift 5 of the 6 stems a little bit so that they all appear.